# Question regarding an inequality of a function which is holomorphuc in first variable and anti-holomorphic in second variable

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $D$ be a domain in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, where $n>1$. Let $F:D×D\to\mathbb{C}$ be a function defined as: $F(z,w)$ is holomorphic function in first variable $z$ and $F(z,w)$ is anti-holomorphic in second variable, $w$. My question is if $F(z,z)\leq0$ for all $z\in \{z:\operatorname{dist}(z,\partial D)<\delta\}$, where dist($z,\partial D$) denote the Euclidean distance of $z$ to the $\partial D$ for sufficiently small positive real number, $\delta>0$. Then can we imply that $F(z,z)\leq 0$ for all $z\in D$? My attempt was if there exist a point $p\in D$ with $F(p,p)>0$, then there exist a ball with centre $p$ and radius $r$, $\mathbb{B}^{n}(p,r)$ such that $F(w,w)>0$ for all $w\in\mathbb{B}^{n}(p,r)$ by continuity of $F$. Then I am not able to move forward. It would be a great help to me if someone can give a hint or something.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. It was a typo.

Comment: How about $D$ the unit ball (given by $\sum_{i=1}^n |z_i|^2 <1$) and $F(z,w)=1-2\sum_{i=1}^n z_i \overline{w_i}$?

Comment: Yeah it concludes that what I was thinking was wrong. As you supplies a counter.